# yet another problem with scanf of char arrays in c?

Tags: c, arrays, input, char, scanf

I have this code that work:

```
 int main()
    {
        char a[100];
        int i;
        int n=3;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            printf("insert char \n");
            scanf("%c",&a[i]);
            getchar();
        }
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            printf("%c ",a[i]);
        }
    }
```

I insert a b c he prints a b c, so far so good, I would like to be able to insert the size n with a scanf, but if I put a scanf of n like this:

```
int main()
        {
            char a[100];
            int i;
            int n;
            scanf("%d",&n);
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                printf("insert char \n");
                scanf("%c",&a[i]);
                getchar();
            }
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                printf("%c ",a[i]);
            }
        }
```

when I run the program, it causes problems in the second for loop, I enter a b c, and the second for returns empty characters,actually does newline n times,in C when each program finishes "PROCESS RETURNED etc." is printed. When I run the first code the characters are printed on the same line and in the next line there is "PROCESS RETURNED", instead with the second code after the insertion n empty lines are printed and then "PROCESS RETURNED" even if I have not written \ n in the printf. I tried to see if n is stored in the same location as some element of a (with printf ("% p", & a [i]), or printf ("% p", & a) and printf ("% p", & n )), but the address is different. Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if first program since you `scan` chars first , there is nothing in buffer then you call `getchar` which will take `\n` as input , but in second program after entering `int n` you have one `\n` in buffer(`scanf` take only one integer and leave `\n` in buffer) , so when you call `scanf` for your charecter it will take that `\n` as input.

so I suggest to add one space in `scanf`:

```
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                printf("insert char \n");
                scanf(" %c",&a[i]);//add space here
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, so it works but I don't understand why, if in the "printf (" insert char \ n ")" I don't write "\ n" I still have the same wrong output ie with empty lines

Comment: @gianlucavallo Tip: Use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of user input and then parse it.  Don't use `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

Comment: @gianlucavallo it's not about `printf`. In your `scanf` function ,in order to take `int n` as input , you will enter one integer and then press `enter` key. .Here `scanf` takes that integer as input but leave that `\n` which is entered by pressing `enter key` in buffer.

Comment: @gianlucavallo `scanf` takes exactly as you said , if you use `scanf("%d",&n)` it will take `int`n` and nothing more. which means when you press enter key the `\n` character created by it will be left in buffer.

Comment: @gianlucavallo feel free , there is no need for thanks ,but accept the answer if this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `getchar()` after reading `n` because the newline character '\n' will remain in the input buffer and your second `scanf` in `for` loop will read that.

Also you should start with index `0`. You can try the following code.

```
int main()
 {
   char a[100];
   int i;
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   getchar();
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("insert char \n");
    scanf("%c",&a[I]);
    getchar();
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   printf("%c ",a[I]);
  }
 }
```